# select catalog field is Empty in sitecore Commerce 10

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am working in sitecore commerce 10.I have setup Development Environment in sitecore Commerce 10.after that I could not see the catalog. But in Business tool I can see the catalogs in Merchandising Dashboard. and I couldn't update the data template also.

Here are the steps that I tried to resolve:

1.Cleared Caches.

2.Reset iis.

3.Recycle App pool.

4.Bootstrap the application.

5.Rebuild the indexes.

but still unable to resolve. can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

[image]

In log file I found below Error Message

```
ERROR Commerce.Connector - Request URL: GetEntityView() - Exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CommerceRepository.GetClient(Boolean useCommerceOps, String language, String environment, String currency, String shopName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CommerceRepository.InvokeHttpClientPost(String serviceCallUrl, StringContent content, Boolean useCommerceOps, Boolean raiseException, String language, String environment, String currency, String shopName, Nullable`1 effectiveDate, String policyKeys)
Exception: System.UriFormatException
Message: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
Source: System
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CommerceRepository.GetClient(Boolean useCommerceOps, String language, String environment, String currency, String shopName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CommerceRepository.InvokeHttpClientPost(String serviceCallUrl, StringContent content, Boolean useCommerceOps, Boolean raiseException, String language, String environment, String currency, String shopName, Nullable`1 effectiveDate, String policyKeys)
```

In business tool the url is run as not secure
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue during Sitecore 9, so I noticed a couple of things -

1. Go to Bizfix website under inetpub (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreBizFx\assets) and check `config.json` and check the urls there.
2. Open `showconfig` (https://xyz/sitecore/showconfig.aspx) and search for **shopsServiceUrl** and **sitecoreIdentityServerUrl**, and check if these urls are correct.

In my case `shopsServiceUrl` was wrong.

After updating these URLs, just do IISRESET and check again.

For more updates visit my blog - https://sitecorerocksblog.wordpress.com/2020/05/20/commerce-catalogs-are-not-showing-for-selection-in-sitecore/

Comment: Thanks, @Gaurav This worked for me pretty well, in my case as well shopsServiceUrl was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue on Sitecore 9.3 where Sitecore login page did not redirect to the Identity Server site.
Here is how I found where the problem was:

- Open Powershell
- Navigate to the Identity Server site physical folder
- Execute command `dotnet .\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll`

This verifies whether your Identity Server is working or not.

In my case, Identity Server license was expired.
So I replaced license file in the physical location `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\identity_server\sitecoreruntime` and now I can see the Catalog under "Selected Catalog"